# Can I add class attribute in JHTMLGrid?

Tags: joomla-3.x, custom-component

I am trying to add class attribute in the checkboxes.

> https://docs.joomla.org/API15:JHTMLGrid/id

I read the documentation but no luck today :(

Please check the image (Thats just an example)
[image]

So my question is, can we add class attribute in `JHtml::_('grid.id', $i, $item->id);` ??

Is there any way to do this **without hacking core**

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of  all, this documentation is very old. Latest is [here](https://api.joomla.org/cms-3/classes/JHtmlGrid.html).

You can't just add class to that. You would have to create your own `JHtml*` class and override it there. Following is just example, you can rename class and file names if you prefer.

**components/your_component/html/mygrid.php**

```
abstract class JHtmlMygrid
{
    public static function id($rowNum, $recId, $class = null, $checkedOut = false, $name = 'cid', $stub = 'cb')
    {
        return $checkedOut ? '' : '<input type="checkbox" id="' . $stub . $rowNum . '"'.(is_string($class) ? ' class="'.$class.'"' : '').' name="' . $name . '[]" value="' . $recId
            . '" onclick="Joomla.isChecked(this.checked);" />';
    }
}
```

Then in your view template, for example **myview/tmpl/default.php**, add your class to `JHtml` include paths.

```
JHtml::addIncludePath(JPATH_COMPONENT.'/html');
```

**Note:** you could add this code to your component main file, then you will be able to use it in every view without repeating this line.

And finaly call it in your template file.

```
JHtml::_('mygrid.id', $i, $item->id, 'class-name');
```

Then Joomla! will automatically call your `JHtmlMygrid` class method `id`.

Comment: It worked!!! :) I have learnt something new today. Thank you @Rene